# How do u remove an iPad virus

Tags: ipad, virus, apple-hardware-test

I have an iPad Air 2 using netstat app. showed me I have compute-1.amazonaws.com running I googled it an it said its a virus. Does anyone no how to remove it I've cleared browser history, factory reset ipad. still no luck. Also have alot off https & http addresses running an some other random addresses like getclicky.com no idea how to fix this if anyone no's how to or has any ideas how to. id really appreciate any advice you's have.

Also have a updatebrainservice log bug type 185.
& webkit bugtype 185

Never been jail broken always has the latest updates installed

Comment: I don't think it is a virus, see this: http://superuser.com/questions/472217/why-is-my-ipad-connecting-to-s3-and-using-lots-of-bandwidth

Comment: I read it thank you I don't use iCloud though. I always have it off.

Comment: @user80770 First thing that should assure you nothing wrong is that the url is amazonaws.com thats a popular "hosting" company which companies can store their user's data on. Unless you're a developer, or someone experienced in this field, don't bother as it'll only confuse you and put you off.

Answer (score 5):

[Netstat app](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/netstat/id400071873?mt=8) is not an application for viewing running processes, but checking your network connections, to see what you are accessing.

This means that the aforementioned compute-1.amazonaws.com is not running, but a connection one of the apps on your phone has made.

Anyways, this is not a virus, compute-1.amazonaws.com is a service commonly used to run web services from, and one of your apps is talking to this web service.

iOS is highly secure so it is unlikely that you'd be able to get a virus, there aren't any at the moment.

Are you seeing symptoms of an issue, because if not, and if you've done a restore, you can safely assume there is no virus or issue.

Comment: How about 1.85 logs webkit & brain service updates and thank you for that information u cleared my head. I no my router is infected an I am changing it but I don't what to connect the iPad to the new router if there is a possibility that I can get infected again. Very paranoid.

Comment: Yeah seriously paranoid, again it's extremely unlikely a router would get a virus, I think you need to relax. Your router and other devices almost certainly don't have a virus.

Comment: Na my router is infected the firmware is changed telnet is turn on services r hidden I have unknown static ips on routor.  Was hack through telnet client protocol. Not paranoid with router I had a MacBook 4 days it got infected to the point that when I turn it one every time it would come up saying that I had to re download Yosemite again. So that's why I'm paranoid with iPad especially with the ssl venerability that Apple always says the fix but never do.. Which has a lot to do with 1.85 bugtype.

Comment: Okay, anyway, I have given my answer, you don't have a virus, iOS has a sandboxed architecture, it's extremely unlikely. And I don't wish to engage with any more paranoid belief that everything that a computer does wrong is a virus. It's much more likely your MacBook has a software fault than a virus.

Comment: Installed Winebottler downloaded malwarebytes over 20 viruses detected! Yeah thanks for ur help =)

Comment: @user80770 Wine etc runs windows and so you have found Windows viruses - noway IOS ones - they run on different machines and CPUs

Comment: I never had a windows computer connected to the router only my I phone iPad an a new MacBook that I only had for 4 days. I no my router is hacked all I have now is my iPhone an iPad an there both playing up like crazy. If I restore the ipad in safe mode with I tunes should that fix it or could any bug in it go back to the new router I set up. It's just a weird situation.